# How to login with Google in Microsoft Word Add-In

Tags: oauth-2.0, ms-office, google-authentication, word-addins, google-auth-library

In the link below it is suggested to use `Google Auth Lib`, but the `github` link provided does not refer to any javascript library:

- [Authorize external services in your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins)

As far as I know I cannot use the `Code FLow` as it needs a redirect URL. How should I get `Access Token` from `Google` in `Microsoft Word Add-In`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to Login using `Google`, `Facebook`, etc you can use `office-js-helpers`:

Install it using `npm`:

```
npm install --save @microsoft/office-js-helpers
```

And in your code, inside of `Office.initialize`:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    //...
    // This to inform the Authenticator to automatically close the authentication dialog once the authentication is complete.
    if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) return;

    // register Google endpoint using
    authenticator.endpoints.registerGoogleAuth('GOOGLE-CLIENT-ID');
    authenticator
         .authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.Google)
         .then(function (token) { console.log('_GOOGLE_TOKEN: ', token); })
         .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
}
```

That's it!